# Extract elements from a vector in Scala

Tags: scala

How can i extract the elements from a vector:

```
val vec = Vector[Vector[Int]];
```

I need to build a `List[((x:Int,y:Int),elem:Int)]` where x and y are the coordinates and elem is the element>5 otherwise is not inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? Also, if this is homework, please tag it as such.

```
val vec = Vector(Vector(1,2,3), Vector(4,5,6), Vector(7,8,9))
val res_v = for {
  (inner, i) <- vec.zipWithIndex
  (x, j) <- inner.zipWithIndex if x > 5
} yield ((i, j), x)

res_v.toList
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Was an artifact of the REPL